# Sentence structure and order

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, word-order

I'm Reading Kafka on the shore, and came across the following sentence:

> **No sooner do I settle down than my consciousness**, like a battery that's lost its charge, starts to fade away, and I fall asleep.

I don't really understand the order and structure of this sentence, would it be wrong to word the bold part like this?:

> No sonner than my consciousness, I do settle down.

is this sentence structure the same as something like this?

> Never again Will I go there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not run across "this sentence"--it's not a sentence. Please quote the entire sentence: *No sooner do I settle down than my consciousness, like a battery that's lost its charge, starts to fade away, and I fall asleep*. Without that the quote is meaningless.

Comment: As I stated, I had no trouble understanding its meaning but the structure and word order to it... Also, i'm nowhere good with technical terms in foreign languages, for that I'm sorry.

Comment: The original sentence doesn't have a comma after "No sooner", so I've edited your question to reflect that.  Adding a comma there makes it more confusing, because one doesn't belong there.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks, and I'm sorry for that... I didn't notice at all.

Comment: **No sooner** invokes subject-verb inversion.  **No sooner** *do I* settle down... **No sooner** *had we* arrived when....    [and it's a translation of Kafka].

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo One last question, would it be wrong to say "I settle down no sooner than my consciousness."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the gap between *settling down* and *his consciousness starting to fade* is non-existent, because the *settling down* does not happen *any sooner* than the latter begins.

The *do I* is simply part of the same word-ordering as is beginning with *no sooner*. You could possibly reorder it as *I do not settle down any sooner than …*, or as *I settle down no sooner than …*, but the order you quote is the most, er, *poetic*. Its purpose is to emphasize the *no sooner*.

[*no sooner* at LDCEO](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/no-sooner-had-did-than)

Comment: Thank you, that was where I was has having troubles the most!

Answer (score 1):

> No sooner, do I settle down than my consciousness.

means there is a *time* when you

> settle down

and

> no sooner

happens exactly when you "***settledown***"

so the meaning  is

> Just when I settle down, my consciousness

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, I get the overall meaning. What's tricking me is two things: 1 - Why "do I" and not "I do".

2 - Usually when comparing things, I thought that the "measurement condition" should be next to "than", I assume I'm wrong.

Eg: "No sonner than my conciousness", "He is stronger than me"... could I say "Stronger, I think he is than me." ?